# Jetpack Compose: Could not set unknown property 'useIR'

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, androidx, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to compile AndroidX's Jetpack Compose following the instructions available at the [README.md file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/ui/README.md) with Android Studio 3.5 Beta 1 and I'm getting the following error from Gradle:

> ERROR: Could not set unknown property 'useIR' for task
>   ':ui-android-view:compileDebugKotlin' of type
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.

To get the code I followed the instructions described on section [Checking Out the Code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/). Then, I imported the project on Android Studio 3.5 Beta 1 in a macOS Mojave 10.4  and when Gradle runs for the first time, I get the error.

Answer (score 3):

As of May 2019, Jetpack Compose is still in a pre-alpha, and uses a experimental versions of both Kotlin and AndroidStudio.  It sounds like you downloaded a copy of AS 3.5 Beta, but you need to run it with the bundled version of studiow that supports jetpack compose, as described here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/#using-android-studio

Answer (score 2):

Run `./studiow` inside `frameworks/support/ui`, not inside `frameworks/support`

They use different version of Android Studio for each subprojects.

See [support/buildSrc/studio_versions.properties](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/buildSrc/studio_versions.properties) and [support/ui/studio_versions.properties](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/ui/studio_versions.properties). `studiow` uses these files to decide what version of Android Studio to use.

*code chunk from studiow*:

```
function runStudioMac() {
  appPath="$(findStudioMacAppPath)"
  echo "open ${appPath}"
  env STUDIO_PROPERTIES="${projectDir}/idea.properties" \
      STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS="${projectDir}/../development/studio/studio.vmoptions" \
      KOTLIN_OVERRIDE="1.3.30-compose-20190503" \
      open -a "${appPath}" "${projectDir}"
}
```

If you launch Android Studio directly from `ui/studio/android-studio-idea-xx/Android studio.app`, it will throw build error as the properties are bootstrapped only when you launch through `ui/studiow`.

+And do not use `git pull` directly from Android Studio. Use `repo sync -j8 -c` in the root directory to sync. I got some issues when I did that.

Answer (score 1):

In the Google I/O Romain Guy said JetpackCompose in development stage. Not even alpha. I faced this problem too because of wrong download.I think you too. I wrote an article "How You Can Install JetpackCompose" to your development machine step by step.
[Article Link](https://medium.com/@halil.ozcan/how-to-install-jetpackcompose-a94b9e94b385)